# Swift: Creating Model Class from JSON with Failable Initializer

Tags: swift, initialization

I'm trying to implement some classes which can be initialized with JSON data `[String : AnyObject]`. Failable initializers appear to be perfect for this use case, but I can't seem to get the syntax correct (without creating ugly code).

Is it possible to do something like this?:

```
class Person {
  let firstName: String
  let middleName: String?

  init?(JSONData data: [String : AnyObject]) {
    do {
      try {
        self.firstName = data["firstName"] as! String
        self.middleName = data["middleName"] as? String
      }
    } catch {
      return nil
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: That's not how Swift exceptions work.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

This is how I usually define model types with a failable initializer.

```
struct Person {
    let firstName: String
    let middleName: String?

    init?(JSONData data:[String:AnyObject]) {
        guard let firstName = data["firstName"] as? String else { return nil }
        self.firstName = firstName
        self.middleName = data["middleName"] as? String
    }
}
```

### Why a Struct?

As you can see I use a Struct instead of a Class, there are at least 2 big reasons for this:

- `failable initializers` work better with structs because you can return `nil` without having initialized all the stored properties
- they are **faster** (because saved on the Stack instead of the Heap)

### Why guard let?

I also prefer using the `guard let` construct because it makes clear that if some mandatory value is not retrieved then the initialisation must fail.

### More

My version of the initializer do not require `middleName`. I decided so because you defined `middleName` as an optional. However if you want to make `middleName` mandatory just change `Person` as shown below

```
struct Person {
    let firstName: String
    let middleName: String

    init?(JSONData data:[String:AnyObject]) {
        guard let
            firstName = data["firstName"] as? String,
            middleName = data["middleName"] as? String else { return nil }
        self.firstName = firstName
        self.middleName = middleName
    }
}
```

### Wait, Structs are value types! I'm going to waste lots of memory with every copy 😱

Nope!

> [...] Swift only performs an actual copy behind the scenes when it is
>   absolutely necessary to do so. Swift manages all value copying to
>   ensure optimal performance, and you should not avoid assignment to try
>   to preempt this optimisation.
>
> [The Swift Programming Language](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Swift/Conceptual/Swift_Programming_Language/ClassesAndStructures.html)

Comment: Thank you, I like this solution. And thanks for pointing out that little piece about structs not copying unless necessary. That's precisely why I was avoiding them, haven't come across that piece of documentation before.

Comment: Structs are better if you just have read only scenarios beyond initialisation. If you want to pass around model and want to see back the mutation, then you will need to use class though

Comment: Can I use .decode from JSONDecoder in init? Something like self = JSONDecoder().decode(Person.self, from: JSONData) ? Ofcourse JSON data would be "Data" object from a valid JSON file.